# can't install Openopt in python 3

Tags: machine-learning, svm, quadratic-programming

I have upgrade my pip.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

And used

```
sudo pip install openopt
```

> its say
>
> ```
> Collecting sortedcontainers
> ```
>
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/f3/cf85f7c3a2dbd1a515d51e1f1676d971abe41bba6f4ab5443240d9a78e5b/sortedcontainers-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Processing
>   ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/e6/b1/a6/9719530228e258eba904501fef99d5d85c80d52bd8f14438a3/setproctitle-1.1.10-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl
>
> Installing collected packages: sortedcontainers, setproctitle, openopt
>   Successfully installed openopt-0.5629 setproctitle-1.1.10 sortedcontainers-2.1.0

```
from openopt import QP
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openopt'

Comment: I would recommend not to run pip with sudo, as you might have screwed up your python installation from a package manager.

Comment: OpenOpt seems to be no longer maintained.